# Changing the default python on RedHat 6

Tags: linux, redhat, python

We have a cluster consists of 5 machine for running Apache spark.

One of the machine the default python is 2.7 and the command `which python` output the following path `/usr/local/bin/python`

The other 4 machine, the default python is 2.6 and the command `which python` output the following path `/usr/bin/python`.

How can I change the python on the first machine to be like the others?

Comment: Do you have python 2.6 installed on first machine? If yes, check your `$PATH` variable to see if `/usr/bin` is put at the first order.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the machines have different version of the same OS or even different OS.

You could  manage different version of Python using for example virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper.

After that you install the packages you want in your /env installation/

[more info about virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)